# Indecomposablity in purely inseparable extensions

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, fields, characteristic-p

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p$ (e.g. the separable closure of $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$) and consider the extension $k(x)/k$ where $x^p\in k$ but $x$ does not. Consider a (finitely generated) noncommutative $k$-algebra $A$ and a finite dimensional $A\otimes_kk(x)$-module $M$, that is finite dimensional. If $M$ is indecomposable and not defined over $k$ (i.e. there does not exist an $A$-module $N$ such that $M=N\otimes_kk(x)$ is it true that $M$ is still indecomposable, when viewed as an $A$-module?

This question arised when considering the case of the map $k(x)\to k(x)$ given by multiplication by $x$. We may view this as a module under $k[T]$. Is there a clean statement to make me understand what's going on in general? I guess this must be obvious to many people.

Of course, for a separable extension $k(t)/k$, there is no hope that this is true: multiplication by $t$ is diagonalizable over $k(t)$. However, in the purely inseparable case we get a Jordan block.